# Button Stays on Screen between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

In an android application I'm writing I have a button that when pressed transitions to a new activity using intents. This new activity has LinearLayout, then a FrameLayout inside of it. When I reach this new activity the button from the previous activity is still on screen and still can be tapped; however, this causes the application to crash because the onClick method isn't defined in this new activity.

Any idea why the button remains? Ideally I'd like to remove the button.

EDIT, ADDING CODE:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: We'll need to see your code to help figure out why. The logcat crash could be helpful too.

Comment: Make sure that your are not using the same layout for the two activities.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show us the code? easier to see, anywho try using something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.bSubmit:
                if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0){
                Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                basket.put***("key"); //depening on what your trying to transfer to one class to the other, this will be different.
                Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Other.class);
                i.putExtras(basket);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
break;
```

that should be on the activity your trying to send something from. Btw using intent works, but bundle(s) are preferd as far as i know.

Also to retrive it go on the other.java and write something like this: (inside onCreate)

```
Bundle basket = getIntent().getExtras();
        a = basket.get***("key")
```